# put together .text, .rdata, .data, .code to a exe(cutable) file

Tags: windows, exe, executable, portable-executable, rdata

I get zip.exe from http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip
I have unpacked the files to:

- .text
- .rdata
- .data

How to connect together through a command line using an external program or without?

```
copy /B .text+.rdata+.data zip.exe
```

The above code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just glue together sections of a PE or ELF file and expect to get a working executable because there's more information needed, namely a number of headers that describe those sections and other important things.

At any rate, I'm not sure why you're dealing with this in first place. zip.exe downloads just fine from that page. I see no reason to break it only to be unable to later repair it.

Answer (score 0):

the unzipping feature of winrar is something rather for fun its kinda easter egg i think, that ilustrates the fact that exe has some internal format that contains section, but you shouldnt unzip it really as an user (only someone could do this for some reverse engeenering attempt, like hex viewing a contents of an exe)... so simply dont unzip exe you wouldnt need to pack it together then.. exe is exe dont unzip it